configuring Wordpress on azure app service to avoid canonical issues
I am a non programmer and am looking to host an educational site using word press on Azure app services with azure front door. I learnt about canonical issues and wanted to ensure that the following requests all point to a standard version of the site
www.websitename.com or random capitalized versions of these with or without a trailing slash http versions with or without www or trailing slash.
I was able to get all of these to work. However, the following 2 versions do not seem to work regardless of what rules I set : https://websitename.com does not redirect to https://websitename.com/ [This is the Standard version I am seeking to redirect all versions of the site to] https://WebSitename.com does not redirect to the standard version (the case won't become small case)
I tried chatgpt and changed the php site but crashed the site a few times without accomplishing what I seek. Any suggestions on whether this matters and how I could accomplish this?
A bonus would be if there was a simpler way to reroute all incoming requests to the destination using https:// without www. and always having a trailing slash and not modifying the destination or the string. Thank you!
What I've done: Set up WP on Azure App service and added 2 of the site names (with and without www) to my domains. Set the AFD route to point appropriately to the origin. Added 2 rules that work: If incoming request is http, reroute to standard version and if incoming request is www, reroute to the standard version and these 2 rules helped with all the ones I mentioned above. However the last two redirects seem to be impossible to get right despite several hours of trying various rule combinations and suggestions. When I tried to edit using terminal or the php site, I've crashed the site several times and had to start over. If url does not end with /, rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent; either does not work or ends in a loop. Thank you for your help.
